# What does -y mean in an apt-get upgrade command, and where can I find a reference on command flags?

Tags: command-line, apt, documentation

I have seen commands like this:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

I would like to know the meaning of the `-y` flag and a reference for Linux command line flags in general.

Comment: Have you tried `man apt-get`  (ie. ask your system to show you the reference MANual page for `apt-get`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `man apt-get` to see what's available.

`man` will show you the **man**ual reference page for the command that follows it, and what options are available for that command for your release.

It'll tell you

> ```
>    -y, --yes, --assume-yes
>        Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation,
>        such as changing a held package, trying to install an unauthenticated package or removing an essential package occurs
>        then apt-get will abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.
> ```

(*as this was done a 19.10 box; your page may be different, but will perfectly match your release of Ubuntu*)